# Jmeter $__Random() with user defined variables

Tags: jmeter, user-defined-functions

I have an issue I have been struggeling with for some time.
In my script I'm calculating a max and min value. I save it using:

```
int minWaitPregancy_acutall=0.2*maxWaitPregancyWait;
int maxWaitPregancy_acutall=0.8*maxWaitPregancyWait;

vars.putObject("minWaitPregancy_acutall", minWaitPregancy_acutall);
vars.putObject("maxWaitPregancy_acutall", maxWaitPregancy_acutall);
```

So far so good, it is saved and I can see it using the debugger.
Now I would like to use it in say a "Uniform Random timer".
I set the constant delay to 0 and in the Random Delay Maximum I try thing like:

```
${__Random(${__eval(vars.getObject("minWaitPregancy_acutall"))},${__eval(vars.get("maxWaitPregancy_acutall"))})}
```

For some reason that (and other variations, like skipping __eval) doesn't work I get variations of:
"java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "vars.getObject("minWaitPregancy_acutall")""

So I guess I don't understand how to retrieve and use the data from the user defined variables. Any help??

Answer (score 1):

1. As per [Elements of Test Plan -> Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder)

   > ```
   > 0. Configuration elements
   >
   > 1. Pre-Processors
   >
   > 2. Timers
   >
   > 3. Sampler
   >
   > 4. Post-Processors (unless SampleResult is null)
   >
   > 5. Assertions (unless SampleResult is null)
   >
   > 6. Listeners (unless SampleResult is null)
   > ```
2. As per [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) documentation:

   > The User Defined Variables element lets you define an **initial** set of variables, just as in the Test Plan.
   >
   > Note that all the UDV elements in a test plan - **no matter where they are - are processed at the start.**

---

It looks like you're using the wrong test element, if you want to calculate a random variable and save it you need to use a [PreProcessor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/quick-guide-jmeter-preprocessors), for example [User Parameters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters)

Comment: Hi! The variables are new (defined in runtime), does it matter?